# sliding-scan problem when gmaping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I met error when i use gmaping:**

in rviz , i see the simulated position is 1/2 of the reality, when i was using `gmapping` + `laser_scaner` to build the map.

when I echo the topic `/odom` , it shows me the right value. is there experts tell me how to configure this?

please see the figure below:

Thank You Very Much!!

[image: image description]

I refered the gmaping wiki page and met the tf requirements. I'm using `ros_indigo`.

**my Question is:**
How to configure my gmapping or other things to make the /scan can be relative static with /map? so I can build reasonable map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246920/sliding-scan-problem-when-gmaping/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-10-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-10-31**:
using `arduino_ros_bridge`; `neato_xv11_driver`; `robot_setup_tf` and `teleop_twist_keyboard`

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-11-02**:
What is the actual question here?

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-02**:
How to configure my gmapping or other things to make the /scan can be relative static with /map? so I can build reasonable map.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-11-02**:
What you describe is similar to what is mentioned in [this tutorial](https://goo.gl/rzzYwE) on setting up a navigation stack. It seems as if your transnational odometry is underestimated. How eactly are you checking that the /odom topic is correct? Are you comparing it with a physical measurement?

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-03**:
thank shoemakerlevy9! I did check the /odom data and the real distance robot moved. less than 5% error. I correct this sliding-scan problem by using the [launch file](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1/blob/indigo-devel/rbx1_nav/launch/gmapping.launch). but I met another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems like that some parameters for gmapping/slam_gmaping are incorrectly configured.

I did check the /odom data and the real distance robot moved. less than 5% error.

Finally, I corrected this *sliding-scan* problem by using the [launch file given by rbx1](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1/blob/indigo-devel/rbx1_nav/launch/gmapping.launch). but I met another problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/247119/how-to-configure-gmapping-params-to-make-the-map-denser/

The map is like drawn with light strockes. And there are many emissive lines which is not as the reality and should be get rid of.

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0